# Val_loss not converging to 0, is my result acceptable?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I'm trying to make a CNN model that is a binary classifier, trying to distinguish between Electronic and Non electronic waste.

Although i'm getting around 90% on the val_accuracy, my loss converge to 0 while my val_loss stales at 0.3 ~ 0.2.

I have tryed differents architetures for the model, techniques for regularization as dropout, batch normalization, kernel regularizes, data augmentation and even synthesize the dataset in differents ways, none of this was able to converge my val_loss to 0.

here is a confusion matrix performed at 52 images never shown to the model:

[image]

Model values:
[image]
Accuracy and Loss graphs:

[[image]

[image]

There is only 8 epochs performed because of the earlystop, it starts to overfit by the 15 epoch.

It actually performed well in the dataset shown for the confusion matrix, but is it acceptable to have this flutuation between loss and val_loss? is 0.2 val_loss too much?
Is this sign for overfit? if not, what does this represents?

Comment: This is overfitting, and as I can see it's around $9\%$ on accuracy which is quite large. Try using optimizers like `AdamW` with enough weight decay (like `1e-3`, or 10x less if too severe)